# Folding repeated lines in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a file in which, below is the content.

A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
A
.
.
.
A
Piece of code...
A
A
A
.
.
A

I want something like this using folding in vim

- A
  Piece of code
- A

2 folds are created by folding repeated lines.
This should happen automatically as I open the file. Is it possible by doing it in vimrc?

Answer (score 2):

How about this `:help fold-expr`:

```
setlocal foldenable foldmethod=expr
let &l:foldtext = 'printf("+-%s %d times: %s", v:folddashes, (v:foldend - v:foldstart + 1), getline(v:foldstart))'
let &l:foldexpr = 'getline(v:lnum) ==# getline(v:lnum + 1) && v:lnum < line("$") ? 1 : (getline(v:lnum - 1) ==# getline(v:lnum) ? "<1" : 0)'
```

Comment: I think it would be worth mention what the behaviour of `==#` is for this scenario. So I know that you Ingo are familiar with it, but i add it for other users: `==#` is always case-sensitive. If you don't want that you can use `==?`. Using a normal `==` like *some* people here have done in there answer is usually a bad idea =). It is case-sensitive or insensitive depending on the `ignorecase` setting.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Thanks for adding that note. Actually, I think here `==` would make sense: If the user has `:set ic`, he probably also expects fold comparisons to be made case-insensitive. But I've never used that setting, so it's a pure guess.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I would like to hear your opinion to it: In my (really limited) experience nobody uses the `ic` setting, that's why i think you should avoid to use it. It seems to make sense here, but i think it is rather given by the file(type) given. It depends on what the file does if an lowercase line is interpreted the same as an uppercase line. So i think you should set it explicit in the foldexpr. What is your experience with that kind of stuff?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: I don't like `'ic'`, neither, so it's hard to guess what those users would expect. The way I would solve this here is make this folding on-demand by defining a custom `:FoldRepeatedLines` command. That command could then take an optional `i` / `I` argument that enables / disables ignoring case (and default would be the `'ic'` value).

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible by using `setlocal foldmethod=expr` where you can write your own function:

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=CustomFold(v:lnum)

function! CustomFold(lnum)
  if getline(a:lnum) == getline(a:lnum-1) || getline(a:lnum) == getline(a:lnum+1)
    return '1'
  endif

  return '0'
endfunction
```

However this is untested and you wouldn't want to do it for all files. But it should point you in the right direction. It also would not 100% match your criteria, but once you have a specific problem, you can always ask again